# Secure Secret sharing

Tags: secret-sharing, oblivious-transfer

I'm trying to come up with a new way to do [oblivious transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) that is faster and requires less computation than existing methods. The basis of my method is shamir secret sharing. Below is an example of how the system would work.

Let $C$ be a matrix. The user would like to query the DB for a particular row of $C$ without revealing which row to the server. I can do shamir secret sharing to form a vector indicating which row of the DB to query for as follows.

I have the following systems:

$$F_1(x_1)=s+a_1x_1\\  
F_2(x_1)=s′+a_2x_1\\
F_3(x_1)=s′+a_3x_1\\
F_4(x_1)=s′+a_4x_1\\
F_1(x_2)=s+a_1x_2\\
F_2(x_2)=s′+a_2x_2\\
F_3(x_2)=s′+a_3x_2\\
F_4(x_2)=s′+a_4x_2$$

Unknowns are: $a_1,x_1,x_2,a_2,a_3,a_4,s,s′$

If we have the vectors…

$\vec{A} =[F_1(x_1),F_2(x_1),F_3(x_1),F_4(x_1)]$ and $\vec{B} =[F_1(x_2),F_2(x_2),F_3(x_2),F_4(x_2)]$

each vector is a share of the vector $\vec{E} =[1,0,0,0]$ using Shamir secret sharing scheme. So $E$ indicates which row of the DB that the user wants (in this case, the first row).

We can send the vectors $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ to the server who computes $R_1=\vec{A}C$ and $R_2=\vec{B}C$, and returns $R_1$ and $R_2$ to the user. The user can use Lagrangian interpolation to recover the row of $C$ that was indicated by $\vec{E}$.

There is a problem with this method, however. The system of equations has 8 equations and 8 unknowns. So, by sending $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ to the server, the server would be able to reconstruct $\vec{E}$.

How can I add more unknowns to these equations, to prevent this data leakage from happening while still being able to recover the desired row of matrix $C$?

Comment: Might I ask what's the point of making it "harder to solve"?  The entire point of Secret Sharing is that the problem is impossible to solve if you don't have enough shares, and that is it easy if you do have enough.

Comment: I`m gonna use it( as explained above) to multiply the secret by a matrix, so I should be able to recover the secret(which is the result of multiplication). Thus I`m only using this construction, but I don't want to  allow anybody to reconstruct it. It is more to do with privacy concern than secret sharing.

Comment: So ... does this differ from homomorphic encryption? $\;$

Comment: Homomorphic encryption is not as efficient as this method. It doubles the computation cost at the server side(e.g. if we use Paillier encryption to encrypt the query).

Comment: My general feeling is that there is no way to make your idea secure without major modifications.

Comment: That's my supervisor said and you both may right, however I`m not giving up !

Comment: In need to say that my concern is not about only these 8 equations as I (think that I) can add one more unknown to make it secure if we if we now the sum of each column in C. The main problem is when the number of rows in C or the number of entries in vector E increases.

Comment: I though it might be interesting to you. Today I found that at least three paper published based on this insecure method and then the attack is mentioned on the following paper. It is the topic we were discussing about recently.   http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/621/chp%253A10.1007%252F978-3-642-31540-4_12.pdf?auth66=1401893924_fca5b9bd632445b7bbc7158f73a02ef5&ext=.pdf

Comment: This is interesting. Good find. FYI, if you type @<username> in the comment it will ping the user so they know something was posted for them. I just happened to look back at this. Otherwise I would have had no idea you had posted.

Comment: Note that in their case, $k<n$. In your case, $k=n$.

Comment: Yes you right, but mine is just a simple example of their problem. Indeed the problem can occur when 1) n increases (e.g. we have more shares of a secret) or 2) we have more Fi's(e.g. we have more entries in vector) or 3) both. This is generalized problem of what has been considered in those papers. Because they did not need much s' values.

Comment: @<mikeazo> More over, they used secret sharing as an alternative to encryption,  thus after a while the servers would learn the pattern based on users query.They shared data across different un-trusted servers. In contrast, in our scheme the queries are issued to the all server once and for the next time all equations and coefficients change.